# RF verification for SIMCOM7070 modem

Tags: rf, test-equipment, at-commands, simcom

We have a custom board featuring a SIM7070 modem with two SMA connectors for GSM and GPS.
After fabrication, the boards are passed through some basic tests to check if the device can operate as expected.

In this test we would also like to verify the RF of the GSM and GPS antennas.
This test should make sure the hardware will be able to connect to the network.

How could such a test best be implemented?
Is there a cheap and simple device to test the RF attributes of the board?
Or can we use AT commands to test the connections?
Maybe through a loopback antenna?